# calling a php from javascript as src file

Tags: php, javascript

i have a question 
when a .php file called as a javascript what dose this mean? and when this is needed to be used ?

ex:

```
<head> 
<script src="dir/myphpfile.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This is essentially how JSON-P works.

Comment: @TheZ no particular reson to assume Json being returned. It could just as easily be a way tu return all script in one request or to include server vars in a script.

Comment: @mplungjan The PHP call to the server will return Javascript (be it static or dynamic) lest it throw an error in the browser. JSON-P is just JSON that has been wrapped up to look like Javascript so that the browser can load it in from any domain.

Comment: I know this. I would rarely expect JSON in a script tag, just normal scripts. Most JSONP I have seen is invoked using appends to the head

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that the `myphpfile.php` would generate javascript code as output instead of HTML because that's all that the web browser could understand in a `script` tag. It is useful in situations when you want to generate dnyamic javascript at runtime instead of statically coding it in a separate `.js` file. Think for example declaring a javascript variable containing the list of customers stored in a database on the server and making this javascript variable globally accessible.

Another common example where this could be useful is to implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) allowing cross domain AJAX requests.

Yet another example is to use a php script that will combine and cache the output of multiple javascript files into one.

Comment: Or if you want to combine multiple JS files via PHP into one file to get less http requests for mobile phones for example.

Comment: @Asto, excellent example. I have updated my answer to include it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @aadiahg, do you have further questions? If not you might consider marking an answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

as Darin Dimitrov said it can be used to generate dynamic javascript at runtime or sometimes also used for on the fly minifying of javascript files.